# Edit user meta on front-end via AJAX

Tags: ajax, user-meta, front-end

**Code below has been updated to reflect answer, and is now a working example;**

*Orignal issue: Below is my code. I built it from the following references but when it runs, I receive no console errors and no errors in my error_log. Nothing is overwritten upon form submit and content is lost on page reload. 
Thanks in advance for any help.*

- [WP Codex for wp_localize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)
- [WP Dev Docs for AJAX in plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/)
- [WP Codex for AJAX in plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

**Javascript (js/custom.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// AJAX
$( '#um_form' ).submit( function() {
    // Grab our post meta value
    var um_val = $( '#um_form #um_key' ).val();
    $.post(my_ajax_obj, { 
       _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce,     //nonce
        action: "my_tag_count",            //action
        'custom_meta': um_val,       
    });
    // Stop form from submitting
    return false;   
} );
//required post-load event
$( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
}); // end document ready
```

**Functions.php**

```
//AJAX
$ajax_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );        // Localized AJAX URL
// Register Our Script for Localization
wp_register_script(
    'custom',                             // Our Custom Handle
    "/wp-content/themes/myTheme/js/custom.js",  // Script URL, this 
script is located for me in `theme-name/scripts/um-modifications.js`
    array( 'jquery' ),                              // Dependant Array
    '1.0',                                          // Script Version ( 
Arbitrary )
    true                                            // Enqueue in Footer
);
// Localize Our Script so we can use `ajax_url`
wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'my_ajax_obj', $ajax_url );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
}

function my_action() {
// Ensure we have the data we need to continue
if( ! isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // If we don't - return custom error message and exit
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 Empty POST Values' );
    echo 'Could Not Verify POST Values.';
    exit;
}

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
//collect & sanitize
$um_val = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_meta'] );
//update info
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_meta', $um_val );

exit;
}

//add AJAX for logged in users only
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_tag_count', 'my_action' );
```

**User-profile.php (custom page type)**

```
<?php    
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
//collect data for rendering
$test1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_meta', true);
?>
<form id="um_form" method="POST">
    <label for="um_key">
        User Meta Value:
        <input type="text" name="um_key" id="um_key" value="<?php echo $test1;?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wp_ajax_` is a prefix for your ajax action. your action is `my_tag_count` so its should be:

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_tag_count', 'my_action' );`

You tried to access the wrong url in the ajax request because you set

`wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'my_ajax_obj', $ajax_url );`

So the the request url should be `my_ajax_obj` its not an object its don't have `ajax_url` in it. So in the request url use only `my_ajax_obj`.

**Another things**

Add to the `get_user_meta` 3rd args to true to get single value instead of array.

`$test1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_meta', true );`

And you don't need to initialze the use meta update will update if exist and if not its will add. so you only need this.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$um_val = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_meta'] );

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_meta', $um_val );
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Looks like I'm still experiencing the same issue though, the value isn't being updated on form submit.

Comment: The ajax code is posted? what is the response?  check in the devtools network tab.

Comment: Looks like it's returning the entire user-profile pages' HTML source.

Comment: See my answer I saw another thing...

Comment: Thanks, updated my code in my post per your revisions. Same issue (value lost on reload) However it looks like devtools > network is returning the correct value (used 'gggg');
  
General;
Request URL:http://austinnorris.website/gtl2/user-profile/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:162.241.244.142:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Form Data;
view URL encoded
action:my_tag_count
custom_meta:gggg

Comment: You forgot to update the request url `$.post(my_ajax_obj, { ` its should be without the `.ajax_url`

Comment: THAT WORKS! You're awesome. Thanks for all the help.